# Visual representation of a 2D array of objects

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose that I obtain an array of objects, e.g.,

```
array([[ 0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g', 'g'],
       [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g'],
       ['d',  0 ,  1 ,  1 , 'g'],
       ['d', 'd',  1 ,  1 , 'g'],
       ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'g']], dtype=object)
```

I want to be able to visually see this as I would for using `plt.imshow` on a `numpy array`. More specifically, I would like to see an image where the region with `g` is some color (maybe yellow), the region with `d` is some color (maybe green) and maybe a colormap that changes for numeric values `0, 1 ,2 , ...` as shown in the example image below.

[image: Sample]

EDIT: It's possible that the numeric values are nonintegers, just floats.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried writing any code to accomplish this? If so, could you share it as a [mcve] and describe what went wrong? If not, please try coding it yourself, then ask a concrete question about a specific coding problem when you get stuck.

Comment: I think the (probably dumb, yet,) most straight forward way is to convert your `np.array` to dtype float32 and then `imshow` with an appropriate cmap, not?

Comment: @ggorlen I think this question really targets "How to use `imshow` with object dtyped numpy array?"

Comment: I'd like to know... your objects are integers —possibly representing Booleans, 0/1— and characters: is your REAL PROBLEM array the same, that is, 0/1 plus characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a good, informative colorbar is absolutely needed in this type of application, even if the OP doesn't mention colorbars in their Q…

[image]

---

The code below is based on the assumption that the integers used in the array are only 0's and 1's

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count

a = np.array([[ 0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g', 'g'], 
              [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g'], 
              ['d',  0 ,  1 ,  1 , 'g'], 
              ['d', 'd',  1 ,  1 , 'g'], 
              ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'g']], dtype=object)

# we want to build a dictionary mapping objects to integers
seq2 = count(2) # we don't know in advance how many different objects we'll see
d = {0:0, 1:1}  # but we know that the integers are either 0 or 1
for o in a.flatten():  
    if o not in d: d[o] = next(seq2)

# with the help of the dictionary, here it is a plottable matrix
b = np.array([d[x] for x in a.flatten()]).reshape(a.shape)

N = len(d)
# to avoid a continuous colorbar, we sample the needed colors
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', N) 

# eventually,
# we can plot the matrix, the colorbar and fix the colorbar labelling
plt.imshow(b, cmap=cmap)
cb = plt.colorbar(drawedges=True)
dc = (N-1)/N
cb.set_ticks([dc*(n+1/2) for n in range(N)])
cb.set_ticklabels([v for k, v in sorted((v,k) for k,v in d.items())])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

---

Post Scriptum

Another answer mentions that (emphasis is mine)

> From the docs, `imshow` does **exclusively** comply with float dtyped arrays

but ① the only requirements is about scalar data, because the "continuous" mapping to the colormap is delegated to a `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` class an ② using a specialized `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` subclass one can directly use the individual integers in the matrix to index the list of colors that is associated to each colormap, e.g.

```
In [34]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: import numpy as np 
    ...: from matplotlib.colors import NoNorm 
    ...: %matplotlib 
    ...:  
    ...: mat_r, mat_i = (np.array(np.arange(6), dtype=float)[None,:], 
    ...:                 np.array(np.arange(6), dtype=int)[None,:]) 
    ...:  
    ...: def show(ax, mat, title, norm=None): 
    ...:     ax.imshow(mat, norm=norm) 
    ...:     ax.set_title(title) 
    ...:     ax.set_yticks([]) 
    ...:  
    ...: fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,1, figsize=(3, 6)) 
    ...:  
    ...: for ax, mat, norm, title in zip( 
    ...:   axes, 
    ...:   (mat_r, mat_i, mat_i, 30*mat_r, 30*mat_i, 30*mat_i), 
    ...:   (None, None, NoNorm(), None, None, NoNorm()), 
    ...:   ('mat_r','mat_i','mat_i NoNorm','30×mat_r','30×mat_i','30×mat_i NoNorm')): 
    ...:      show(ax, mat, title, norm) 
    ...: fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

```
In [35]: plt.cm.viridis.colors[:151:30]                                                   
Out[35]: 
[[0.267004, 0.004874, 0.329415],
 [0.280255, 0.165693, 0.476498],
 [0.237441, 0.305202, 0.541921],
 [0.182256, 0.426184, 0.55712],
 [0.13777, 0.537492, 0.554906],
 [0.128087, 0.647749, 0.523491]]

In [36]:
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let us have a look at `imshow` from the docs: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

From the docs:

> Display an image, i.e. data on a 2D regular raster.

whereas the docs for the image input **X** state:

> **X** : array-like or PIL image
>
> The image data. Supported array shapes are:
>
> (M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a colormap.
>
> (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).
>
> (M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e. including transparency.

From the docs, `imshow` does exclusively comply with float dtyped arrays and hence we need to find a way to convert the dtype from object to float for the array you posted.

---

So, as outlined in my comment: I was thinking of something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

foo = np.array([[ 0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g', 'g'], 
                [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 , 'g', 'g'],
                ['d',  0 ,  1 ,  1 , 'g'],
                ['d', 'd',  1 ,  1 , 'g'],
                ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'g']], dtype=object)

# replace chars by reserved numbers
np.place(foo, foo=='g', -1)
np.place(foo, foo=='d', -2)

# change dtype from object to float
foo = foo.astype(np.float32)

# sanity check
print(foo)

# plot
plt.imshow(foo)
```

where I have not tweaked the `cmap` because this is really sugar on top of it. :-)
The result looks as follows:

[image: resulting imshow]

**Issue:**

- The `imshow` declaration expects the input array to be of `dtype.float`, hence the conversion approach.

**Bonus:**

- The reserved numbers per char can be mapped to the dedicated color in your `cmap` as requested by you.

**Disadavantages:**

- Does not scale very well for arbitrary chars.
- Does use reserved numbers as replacement and thus the set of numeric values for the rest needs to be known and fixed.

I still hope that this answer lends you a helping hand. Cheers!